# Spark API script to extract the number of entries for each month

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to write a Spark API script In Zeppelin notebook, write a Spark API script to extract the number of entries for each month from 6 different `csv` files. Then Plot the number of entries for each month using any preferred plotting tool.

What code do you suggest?

```scala
val fileName = "C:\code\AliceInWonderland.txt"
val lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile(fileName)

val words = lines.flatMap(_.split("\\s")) // Split on any white character
         .map(_.replaceAll("[,.!?:;]", "").trim.toLowerCase) // Remove characters, remove white spaces
         .filter(!_.isEmpty) // Filter out any empty-words
         .map((_, 1)) // Map each word to number 1
         .reduceByKey(_ + _) // Count words
         .sortByKey()
words.take(5).foreach(println)
```